# Comes, will come, coming, be coming

Tags: tense

> He will come tomorrow.
>   He is coming tomorrow.
>   He comes tomorrow.
>   He will be coming tomorrow.

Which one is correct ?

Comment: And what does - He will be coming tomorrow mean?

Answer (score 1):

All four are fully grammatical and natural (I don't do social judgments like "correct"). Why do you think only one might be?

There are very slight difference of nuance between then, but only very slight. *He's coming tomorrow* is the most common in speech, I would say, but all the rest are possible in particular contexts.

*He comes tomorrow* is talking about somebody's plan or intention. I can't articulate any other differences.